# Pasting NULL in INT column of DatagridView generates 'invalid value' error

Tags: c#, type-conversion, datagridviewcolumn

Using a Copy/Paste/Delete ContextMenuStrip I'm copying one row of datagridview and then pasting as new row with change to 1 column to maintain uniqueness.  The DGV is bound to DT and DT has several columns defined as INT that DGV columns inherit.

Some INT columns that are copied are NULL and create a conversion error if I leave as is. Convert and Parse both convert the NULL to 0 but I need values that are NULL to remain NULL since this is an interface to SQL.  A second issue is, after paste the '*' remains on the row as if it doesn't commit and stays that way until I make another selection in my ListView.

How do I get the paste to accept NULL in an INT column?
How I force a commit so * moves to blank line?

```
            // paste
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < rowInClipboard.Length; iRow++)
            {
                if (iRow + currentRow < grid.Rows.Count)
                {
                    string[] cellsInRow = rowInClipboard[iRow].Split(columnSplitter);
                    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cellsInRow.Length; iCol++)
                    {
                        if (grid.ColumnCount > currentColumn + iCol)
                        {
                            DataGridViewCell currentCell = grid.Rows[currentRow + iRow].Cells[currentColumn + iCol];
                            if (!currentCell.ReadOnly) // H.NH added to avoid Read only case.
                                switch (grid.Columns[iCol].ValueType.Name)
                                {
                                    case "Int32":
                                        string s = cellsInRow[iCol];
                                        int result;
                                        if (int.TryParse(s, out result))
                                        {
                                            // The string was a valid integer => use result here
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        }
                                        currentCell.Value = 999;
                                        //currentCell.Value = cellsInRow
                                    break;
                                    case "String":
                                    if (iCol == 3)
                                    {
                                        cellsInRow[3] += "*******";
                                    }
                                        currentCell.Value = cellsInRow[iCol];
                                    break;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using data binding for this? Most of what you appear to be trying to do manually is already provided for you through data binding (all its ugly spots aside).

Comment: But the user interacts with the DataGridView.  I'm still pretty green in the language but don't see how the binding helps when the user doesn't interface with it.  I don't understand why the copy doesn't copy it as integer in the first place.

Comment: I found a workaround for the NULL.  I test for it and if NULL I do nothing and continue iteration.

I still need to find how to force the paste to complete the insert and move the * to a blank row.

Comment: Data binding isn't solely about user interaction; it's about getting data into a control with a minimal amount of effort. In your case, that control would be a `DataGridView`. Further, I suspect that the reason you're running into issues with the data has to do with either a conversion between `DBNull.Value` and `Int32`, or the fact that you're receiving null values from the database and your grid view expects `Int32` values (which can't be `null`) instead of `int?` (`Nullable<int>`) values (which can hold `null` values). Quite possibly, it's both.

Comment: The datatable is populated from SQL table and DataGridView is bound to DT.  INT DT columns are defined as:
tblvAttributes.Columns.Add("DWFieldScale",typeof(int));
I do not do any definition of DGV columns as I expect their attributes/properties are inherited from DT.

Yes there are nulls in the SQL table passed to DT passed to DGV.  I have no idea why DGV expects INT32 instead of INT but when I test value type, grid.Columns[iCol].ValueType.Name, it returns "Int32"

Comment: `Int32` and `INT` are the same thing. `Int32` is the CLR (.NET Framework) type, and the other is the SQL Server or C# type, but they are equivalent. (`int` is the C# alias for `System.Int32`, and `SqlDbType.Int` maps directly to both `int` and `Int32`. )

Comment: Got it.  A real pain for us SQL types.  Anyway I ended up setting INT columns as typeof(Nullable<Int32>) and then setting empty strings to DBNull.  Had to set types of String with empty string to NULL.

The only issue l haven't solved is forcing the DGV Row to update on paste row to new row and move the * to a blank line.